# How do I remove a trigger in a BasedOn Style?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, styles

```
<Style x:Key="originalStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    ...setters...
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding yyy}" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource xxx}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I like everything in the Style except for the DataTrigger which I want to remove.  How can change it?

```
<Style x:Key="derivedStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource originalStyle}">
   ...How to remove the DataTrigger???....
</Style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a "base style" containing all the common stuff, and create two styles `BasedOn` that style.

Comment: What if you don't control the style you want to base on (such as basing it on `VsResourceKeys.ButtonStyleKey`)?